# Accessing packages of newly created package EA

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I've got the following code which creates a new EA Model and a subpackage to that model. However it seems like the subpackage is only updated/created "visually" - by that I mean that I can see it in EA but if I try to get the packages of my new root it returns 0 which should be 1.

```
var root = eaRepo.Models.AddNew("A New Root", "");
root.Update ();
eaRepo.Models.Refresh();

Package newPackage = root.Packages.AddNew("New Package", "Package");
newPackage.Update();
eaRepo.Models.Refresh();

var packages = root.Packages.Count; //Returns 0 but I just created one
```

Any suggestions on why this doesn't work?

Comment: Print `eaRepo.Models.count` and you're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're refreshing the wrong collection (eaRepo.Models, second time). You need to refresh the collection you've added the package to.

```
Package newPackage = root.Packages.AddNew("New Package", "Package");
newPackage.Update();
root.Packages.Refresh();
```

Comment: Do you know a way to prevent it from arranging it in alphabetic order when you refresh?
I'm adding the packages in a specific order but when I run refresh() on the collection it arranges them in alphabetic order.

Comment: The sort order is specified by the TreePos attribute, so if you set newPackage.TreePos = someCounter, and increase someCounter by one for each package you add, that should work.

Comment: It still arranges it in alphabetic order :(